# MySQL select data from table and inner join the union all selection from another two identical tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, union

In a first place I have two tables and I make join with the following query

```
SELECT o5.id AS id, 
DATE_FORMAT(o5.vreme_isplata, '%d.%m.%Y') AS payed_date, 
o5.ime_prezime AS name, 
o5.adresa AS address, 
o5.mesto AS city, 
o5.embg AS mb, 
o5.serial_no AS ticket, 
o1.uplata AS uplata, 
o5.pdd AS danok, 
o5.isplata AS neto_dobivka, 
o1.iznos_isplaten AS bruto_dobivka 
FROM o5 
INNER JOIN o1 
ON o5.serial_no = o1.serial_no 
WHERE o1.transaction_type = 'I'
```

and its work fine
now I need to select data from another table "o1_payout_storno" witch is identical with `o1`
I need to select data from `o5` and `INNER JOIN` the `UNION ALL` selection from `o1` and `o1_payout_storno`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got the query

```
SELECT o5.id AS id, 
DATE_FORMAT(o5.vreme_isplata, '%d.%m.%Y') AS payed_date, 
o5.ime_prezime AS name, 
o5.adresa AS address, 
o5.mesto AS city,
o5.embg AS mb, 
o5.serial_no AS ticket, 
o1.uplata AS uplata, 
o5.pdd AS danok, 
o5.isplata AS neto_dobivka, 
o1.iznos_isplaten AS bruto_dobivka 
FROM o5 
INNER JOIN o1 ON o5.serial_no = o1.serial_no
WHERE o1.transaction_type = 'I' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT o5.id AS id, 
DATE_FORMAT(o5.vreme_isplata, '%d.%m.%Y') AS payed_date,
o5.ime_prezime AS name, 
o5.adresa AS address, 
o5.mesto AS city, 
o5.embg AS mb,
o5.serial_no AS ticket, 
o1_payout_storno.uplata AS uplata, 
o5.pdd AS danok, 
o5.isplata AS neto_dobivka,
o1_payout_storno.iznos_isplaten AS bruto_dobivka 
FROM o5 
INNER JOIN o1_payout_storno ON o5.serial_no = o1_payout_storno.serial_no 
WHERE o1_payout_storno.transaction_type = 'I' 
ORDER BY payed_date ASC
```

It's working as i expected!

Answer (score 0):

It should be strightforward like this:

```
SELECT 
  o5.id AS id, 
  DATE_FORMAT(o5.vreme_isplata, '%d.%m.%Y') AS payed_date, 
  o5.ime_prezime AS name, 
  o5.adresa AS address, 
  o5.mesto AS city, 
  o5.embg AS mb, 
  o5.serial_no AS ticket, 
  o1.uplata AS uplata, 
  o5.pdd AS danok, 
  o5.isplata AS neto_dobivka, 
  o1.iznos_isplaten AS bruto_dobivka 
FROM o5 
INNER JOIN o1 ON o5.serial_no = o1.serial_no 
WHERE o1.transaction_type = 'I' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  o5.id AS id, 
  DATE_FORMAT(o5.vreme_isplata, '%d.%m.%Y') AS payed_date, 
  o5.ime_prezime AS name, 
  o5.adresa AS address, 
  o5.mesto AS city, 
  o5.embg AS mb, 
  o5.serial_no AS ticket, 
  op.uplata AS uplata, 
  o5.pdd AS danok, 
  o5.isplata AS neto_dobivka, 
  op.iznos_isplaten AS bruto_dobivka 
FROM o5
INNER JOIN o1_payout_storno AS op ON op.serial_no = o5.serial_no
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but in the second selection i need to select data from o5 i will try selection from o5 with inner join o1 after that union all selection from o5 with inner join o1_payout_storno